# How to remove invisible elements in SVG files using Python?

Tags: python, xml, svg

How can I clean up SVG files by removing invisible objects or layers with a Python script. Such elements have at least one of the following styles set:

```
display: none
opacity: 0
visibility: hidden
```

I'm considering to use a Regex pattern, but given the complexity of XML, Regex is usually discouraged here.

Would it be an option to use lxml? I can do some HTML modifications, but I'm not sure about SVG and how to properly save the modified data to the file.

Comment: did you try `lxml` ? and what did you get ? show your code and FULL error message.

Comment: I did not try lxml, because I don't know enough about it. I don't even know if that is possible with SVG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse('/test.svg')
for action, el in etree.iterwalk(doc):
    if el.attrib.get('display', None) == 'none' or el.attrib.get('visibility', None) == 'hidden' or el.attrib.get('opacity', None) == '0':
        el.clear()
with open('/test_out.svg', 'w') as f:
    f.write(u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'+etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True))
```

I hope that will catch all cases.

Comment: lxml can write xml_declation directly, no need for string concentration: `f.write(etree.tostring(doc, xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you have an idea on the new issue that came up with this snippet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41920272/strip-out-all-namespace-declarations-tags-and-attributes-from-svg-file-with-pyt